# How to fill the area between two lines using C3 chart?

Tags: c3.js

1. Please open this link: http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html
2. Replace the code of textarea by following code:

   ```
   var chart = c3.generate({
     data: {
       x: 'x',
       columns: [
         ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04',],
         ['bottomline', null,30, 150, 250],
         ['topline', 130, 340, 350,null]
       ]
     },
     axis: {
       x: {
         type: 'timeseries',
         tick: {
           format: '%Y-%m-%d'
         }
       }
     }
   });
   ```
3. You will be able to see a graph like Fig:1 below.
4. Now I want to fill the area between two lines shown in the graph with some color. I want to make it like **Fig:2** below.

   [Fig:1 and then Fig:2](http://e41i.imgup.net/chart33e7a.png)
5. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but just in case someone also meets this problem. Here is a working fiddle for filling between two lines. 
[Fill between two lines](https://jsfiddle.net/Mandyzhu7/4Lq2vob6/1/)

Note: the null points should be handled before feeding to charts since null will be mapped to 0 automatically from C3 point of view.

Code snippet:

```
function fillArea(){
var indexies = d3.range( items.length );
var yscale = chart.internal.y;            
var xscale = chart.internal.x; 

var area = d3.svg.area()
  .interpolate("linear")
  .x(function(d) { return xscale(new Date(items[d].x)); })
  .y0(function(d) { return yscale(items[d].bottomline); })
  .y1(function(d) { return yscale(items[d].topline); });  

d3.select("#mychart svg g").append('path')
  .datum(indexies)
  .attr('class', 'area')
  .attr('d', area);}
```

Comment: This solution does not works when we use x-axis type "category". So, Can you help me with that?

Comment: @SubhashDiwakar [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Mandyzhu7/oc8La3mf/1/). You need to change x for d3.svg.area() to use index, not the value.`function(d, i) => xscale(i)`

Comment: Yes, Used the same, but xscale(i) returns 0 for each index.